# Placing data at an address given by a constant arithmetic expression

Tags: c, arm, embedded, c-preprocessor, compile-time

## Context

My team upgraded our project from using Arm Compiler for Embedded 5 to Embedded 6. In our code, we place data at a specific location in RAM like so:

```
#define RAM_START_ADDR <some constant>
#define OFFSET <some other constant>
...
volatile my_datatype_t __attribute__((at(RAM_START_ADDR + OFFSET))) var = ...;
```

But for some reason, Embedded 6 no longer supports `__attribute__((at(<addr>)))`, and instead, we need to use `__attribute__((section(".ARM.__at_<addr>")))`. As you might have noticed, the address we are dealing with is an arithmetic expression, which is not supported by `__attribute__(section)`, which expects a numeric string argument.  ARM does provide a workaround, namely

```
volatile my_datatype_t * const var = (volatile my_datatype_t *) (RAM_START_ADDR + OFFSET);
```

Except, when this compiles, rather than allocating space for `var`, it just overwrites whatever data is at `RAM_START_ADDR + OFFSET`. Haven't asked ARM how to achieve this, but I'm not confident we'll get anything besides the not-working workaround they already provide.

## Question

Is there a way to evaluate a constant arithmetic expression at compile-time and format it as a string? If so, then we could still use `__attribute__((section))` and just pass it the numeric string.

I've done a lot of research, and there doesn't seem to be a way to define a macro such that the expression is evaluated and the value is accessible as a token or string or anything.

Comment: You can place a specific section with a known name at a calculated address in your linker script instead. If you want it to fetch the symbols for the calculation from your header files, you might add preprocessor directives to it and pass it to `cpp` before linking. Alternatively define these symbols in the linker script and import them in your source code (if needed).

Comment: would be nice to reference the documentation https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100068/0621/Compiler-Source-Code-Compatibility/Language-extension-compatibility--attributes?lang=en#a61-language-extension-compatibility-attributes__supporting-arithmetic-expressions-in-the-ataddress-attribute

Comment: It is a horrible (very naive too) method. First, the linker does not know that you want to place something there and can place something else in the same location. It is the main reason why they scraped this stupid idea.

Comment: @gulpr  They did not scrap it, but still offer an altered syntax.  It is most common when there are two binaries compiled separately that run on the same CPU and run in a flat (no-MMU) address space.  Example are the various Wifi application chips, like nRF, etc.

The vendor provides a soft MAC that is proprietary binary with a scheduler,etc and the OEM places custom code within this framework and tries to remain tool agnostic.  I agree that open source solutions are better.  (Some have switched to Zepher).  Tool vendor might want to support it.  However, developers should try to avoid it.

Comment: @artlessnoise I think you did not understand my comment. Placing at address, not in the section at address is complete nonsense.

Comment: @gulpr  I completely understand.  It is better to use the linker.  If there is only one buffer that needs to be shared, the work of defining linker file (which are different for all tools) maybe complex for a vendor to implement.  It is much easier to say the address is here.  For the case where there is only one item in a section and you don't want to involve tools, it would seem to make sense.  I agree the alternative to put it in a linker script is more robust, but takes more developer time.

Comment: @artlessnoise I 100% disagree.

Answer (score 0):

You are out of luck. This is a preprocessor, if you want to add anything you have to hard-code all possible combinations. This has to be generated with a script. You can try searching for an existing project like Boost, but I do not know or see anything relevant, `BOOST_PP_LIMIT_MAG` is max 1024.

```
// Add two base10 numbers and output them in hex format
#define ADDHEX_1_1()  2
#define ADDHEX_1_2()  3
// generate each possible ADDHEX_*_*
// .... few billion lines later ...:
#define ADDHEX_123_456()  243

#define CONCAT4(a, b, c, d)  a##b##c##d
#define XCONCAT4(a, b, c, d)  CONCAT4(a, b, c, d)

#define STRING(x)  #x
#define XSTRING(x)  STRING(x)

#define RAM_START_ADDR 123
#define OFFSET 456
#define AT(a, b)    XSTRING(XCONCAT4(ADDHEX_, a, _, b)())

#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    puts(".ARM.__at_" AT(RAM_START_ADDR, OFFSET));
}
```